# asp.net core DI - can I make a service dependent on other services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

In my asp.net core 3.1 app I have a RequestInfo class that contains information about the current request, and I'd like to make an instance of RequestInfo availale to middleware and controllers by dependency injection. Obviously the RequestInfo must be constructed for every request, and needs the HttpContext to construct it. I'm registering a transient service like this:

```
services.AddTransient<RequestInfo>(sp =>
  {
    var context = sp.GetService<HttpContext>();
    return new RequestInfo(context)
  });
```

The problem is that when my factory is called, there is no HttpContext in the service provider.

I have tried `addScoped`, and I've also tried putting `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in the top of my ConfigureServices and then calling `sp.GetService<HttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext` in the factory, but neither of those worked.

So what I'm asking is, is there a way to specify that my service factory isn't called until the service provider has already injected the HttpContext.

I realise there are other approaches: I could inject a RequestInfoFactory and then have the consumer call GetRequestInfo on that, or that I could use a middleware to construct the RequestInfo and add it into context.Items. I just want to find out if there's a way to inject the RequestInfo directly because that seems cleaner to me.

Comment: When is `RequestInfo` created? Is creating triggered by an http request?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of getting `HttpContext`, get `IHtttpContextAccessor` service from DI container (it does not make any sense to pass the `HttpContext` from the startup class):

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<RequestInfo>(sp =>
{
    var context = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    return new RequestInfo(context)
});
```

You can alternatively simplify this problem by introducing an `interface` for `RequestInfo`:

```
public interface IRequestInfo
{
}

public class RequestInfo
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
    public RequestInfo(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}
```

and in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IRequestInfo, RequestInfo>();
```

Comment: D'oh! you can see in the original post I actually tried to do this but I was doing `sp.GetService<HttpContextAccessor>`  (I left out the I out of the interface name).

Comment: Sorry I think you misinterpreted my comment. When I said "D'oh" I was castigating myself for making an obvious mistake which you pointed out. I marked your answer as correct and didn't downvote it.

Answer (score 3):

I've got this working by following [Microsoft Docs - use HttpContext from custom components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to inject directly without creating the instance in ConfigureServices.

> The dependency injection container supplies the IHttpContextAccessor
>   to any classes that declare it as a dependency in their constructors.

- Add `IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor` to the class
  constructor.
- Add  `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to
  ConfigureServices.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to register all the dependencies before they are needed as shown below:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<RequestInfo>();
```

Inside the `RequestInfo` class you can ask for `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
public class RequestInfo
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public RequestInfo(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
}
```